# C#: getting extra new line at top in resultant file while skipping bytes for original file

Tags: c#, file, io

I have a text file and I'm trying to skip some bytes of the file and generating a new file, but my resultant file has extra new line at very top like below,

[image]

Here is the code,

```
string outputFile = "Export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";
        using (var outStream = File.Create(outputFile))
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                using (var fileToCompressStream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var x = fileToCompressStream.Length;
                    // Skip the bytes
                    fileToCompressStream.Position = 37174;
                    fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it possible there is a CR+LF (\r\n) pair at 37173, so the position skip has resulted in LF being left in the resulting file? Could you toggle display of special characters to see which exactly is on the first line?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Depending on your text editor - you need to find an option to "show whitespace characters". Which editor are you using?

Comment: Easiest thing to try now - skip 37175 bytes to see if the newline character is gone. If not, try again with 37176. One of those should result in the expected output.

Comment: Yes, `37176` give the expected output, there is a CR+LF (\r\n)

Comment: Awesome :-) . I will rewrite my comment as answer

Comment: Is there any way to remove `CR+LF (\r\n)` programatically?

Comment: Yes, I have added a possible solution to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CR+LF pair at the position 37174, so you need to change it to 37176 to skip this new-line. It could also happen that there was just a LF character there (in case of Unix style files or Windows files where you hit just the position between CR and LF).

If you want to skip whitespace characters at the beginning of the file, I would recommend first to use loop with the `ReadByte` method and skip until you find the first non-whitespace character, which you write to the output and then continue with `CopyTo` to copy the rest.

```
fileToCompressStream.Position = 37174;
while (fileToCompressStream.CanRead)
{
    var nextChar = (char)fileToCompressStream.ReadByte();
    if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar))
    {
        //first non-whitespace character
        targetStream.WriteByte((byte)nextChar);
        break;
    }
}
fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, could you please show some code .... loop with the ReadByte method and skip until you find the first non-whitespace character

Comment: Awesome...Thanks Martin!